# Change GameMode on GameStart

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a question about this function:

```
UWorld::SetGameMode
```

I have let's say 3 GameModes. How can i get access to them in my code and set one of them as default when game starts? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes and close votes? How is this too broad? It's a pretty specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your own `UGameInstance` class (set it in the project settings). In this class you can override this method:

```
/** Call to create the game mode for a given map URL */
virtual class AGameModeBase* CreateGameModeForURL(FURL InURL);
```

And supply whatever gamemode class you wish to use.

Comment: Appreciated your answer :) Could you please show me some usage example of it?

Comment: The best usage example is the default implementation of the method which you can check in GameInstance.cpp.

Comment: Gonna check it then! Thank you once again